# Orthogonal projection.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be the Hilbert space $L^2[0,1]$, and let $S$ be the subspace of functions $f\in H$ satisfying $\int^1_0(1+x)f(x)dx=0$. 
Find the element of $S$ closest to the function $g(x)=1$.

I know that $S$ contains the functions orthogonal to $x \mapsto 1+x$ and what I want to do is find the orthogonal projection of $g$ onto S but I'm not too sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R},\,x\mapsto 1+x$. By the Hilbert projection theorem, $g$ can uniquely be written as $g=u+v$ with $u\in S$, $v\in S^\perp$, and $v$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\mathrm{lin}\{\phi\}$.

One can easily see that $v=\frac{\langle g,\phi\rangle}{\|\phi\|^2}\phi$ (just check that $g-v\perp\phi$). Thus,
\begin{align*}
u(x)=g(x)-v(x)=1-\frac{\int_0^1 (1+x)\,dx}{\int_0^1 (1+x)^2\,dx}(1+x)=1-\frac{9}{14}(1+x)=\frac{1}{14}(5-9x).
\end{align*}